# visual studio code showing wrong autocomplete suggestions in c++

Tags: c++, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am trying to learn SDL in C++ So auto-complete is very essential for me.VS code was working fine with SFML but due to android problems I started learning SDL and now auto-completions for SDL is not working correctly . It always suggest some wrong members ,**even If I didn't include any library** . I don't have enough experience with VS . I came to VS from neovim only for auto completions which not working properly :(

[image]

I had tried restring ,updating and deleting .vscode dir but nothing happened

Comment: Can't those symbols be included indirectly? That is, be declared in headers, that `SDL_video.h` includes?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes they can. But I was still having this problem.So I thought including explicitly might help , but It didn't

Comment: In this case, I can provide no further suggestions, then, since I never used VS Code.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius what do you use ? I really need some nice C++ editor.Your advice will be really helpful :)

Comment: Me? Personally? Visual Studio Professional 2017.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

- Hover your cursor on the header file mentioned in the source code
- You'll notice a red/green swiggly underline
- A light bulb icon appears, click on it
- select the option called "edit includepath setting"
- It takes you to a new "c_cpp_properties.json"
- In this json file, under your platform, add all the paths to the headerfiles

After doing this, most of the unwanted intellisense results disappear. Only releavent ones show up the top.

VS code is a very good tool which comes with source control features. Add C++ extension and a debugger and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks man but this is not working. I tried it already. And as you can see in screenshot there is no green line. I was getting this green line but now I had inserted the full path of library.